# Vuex: Firebase routing. If statement

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I am using firestore and vuex for my project.
And I finished signIn method.

I want to accomplish the following action.

When the user login at first time, the URL will redirect to /selfonboarding to finish the profile setting.

If the user submit all the information and finishes the profile setting, the status field in "proUser" collection is set to be true.

Otherwise, the user does not finish the profile setting, the status remains false until the user finishes all the profile setting.

All the documents have "status" field in "proUser" collection.
So I need to check the status condition one by one.

Now, I need the conditional branch.

Here is what I want to achieve: If proUser collection has the field, "status" == true, the user will redirect to /dashboard/products. And if the collection has "status" == false field, the route will be /selfonboarding.

The problem is, when I login as the user who has "status" == true field, I could go to /dashboard/products.

But even though I login as the user who has "status" == false, the route is still the same.

[image]

My question is why I cannot move to /selfonboarding as "status" == false.

This is my signIn method.

I want to retrieve only one user data, but now I am retrieving all the users who have "status" == true.

```
   import 'firebase/firebase-auth'
import fireApp from '@/plugins/firebase'
import router from '../../router'
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");
const db = firebase.firestore();

const state = {
    currentUser: null
}

const getters = {
    currentUser: state => state.currentUser
}

const mutations = {
    userStatus: (state, user) => {
        // if(user) {
        //   state.currentUser = user
        // }
        // else {
        //   state.currentUser = null
        // }
        user === null ? state.currentUser = null : state.currentUser = user.email
      }
}

const actions = {
 signIn: async ({ commit }, user) => {
    try {
      const userData = await fireApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          user.email,
          user.password
      );

        var userStatus = db.collection('ProUser').where("status", "==", true)

        if(userStatus) {
            userStatus.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                    router.push("/dashboard/products");
                });
                
            })
        } else {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            router.push("/selfonboarding");
        }

        
    }
    catch(error) {
        const errorCode = error.code
        const errorMesage = error.message
        if(errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            alert('wrong password')
        } else {
            alert(errorMesage)
            }
        }
    },

    signOut: async({ commit }) => {
        try {
            await fireApp.auth().signOut()
        }
        catch(error) {
            alert(`error sign out, ${error}`)
        }
        commit('userStatus', null)
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    getters,
    actions
}
```

login.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <img src="../img/svg/Mangosteen.png" alt="">
    <b-card
    class="login-card"
    >
    <form action="" @submit.prevent="signIn">
    <div>
    <b-form>

        <p class="mt-3  text-center login-title">Profile</p>   
    
        <b-form-input
        id="input-3"
        v-model="email"
        type="email"
        required
        placeholder="Email"
        class="mt-5 input"
        name="email" 
        v-validate="'required|email'" 
        :class="{ 'mt-5 input': errors.has('email') }">
        >
        </b-form-input>
        <p v-show="errors.has('email')" class="validate text-center">{{ errors.first('email') }}</p>
        <b-form-input
        id="input-4"
        v-model="password"
        type="password"
        required
        placeholder="Password"
        class="mt-5 input"
        name="password" 
        v-validate="'required|min:6'" 
        :class="{ 'mt-5 input': errors.has('password') }"
        ></b-form-input>
        <p v-show="errors.has('password')" class="validate text-center">{{ errors.first('password') }}</p>
        <error-bar :error="error"></error-bar> 

    </b-form>

    <b-button class="loginbutton-color" type="submit">Login</b-button>
    <div v-if="show">
        <b-button class="loginbutton-color" type="submit">
            <spring-spinner
                :animation-duration="3000"
                :size="27"
                color="#ff1d5e"
                class="loading"
            />
      </b-button>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    </form>
</b-card>

</div>
</template>

<script>
import fireApp from '@/plugins/firebase'
import ErrorBar from '@/components/ErrorBar'
import { SpringSpinner } from 'epic-spinners'
import store from '../store'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        error: '',
        show: false
      }
    },
    components: {
      ErrorBar: ErrorBar,
      SpringSpinner
    },
    methods: {
        signIn() {
            this.show = true
            const user = {
              email: this.email,
              password: this.password
            }
            store.dispatch('signIn', user)
            this.show = false
        },

    }
  }
</script>
```

I hope someone helps me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `var userStatus = db.collection('ProUser').where("status", "==", true)` you define a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) and, therefore, when calling `get()` you get a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) and not a `DocumentSnapshot`. Therefore `doc.exists` always returns `false`, since a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) does not have an `exists` property.

You either need to loop on the `QuerySnapshot` (as shown in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)), or use the `docs` or `size` properties of the `QuerySnapshot` to check if the desired document exists, depending on your exact goal.

---

**Update following the comments below:**

I understand that you wan to check the document with the ID corresponding to the user Id. Do as follows:

```
   // Get the user id (from the user object I guess)
   const userId = user.uid;
   // or maybe through  const userId = fireApp.auth().currentUser.uid;

   const proUserDocRef = db.collection('ProUser').doc(userId);
            
   proUserDocRef.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists && doc.data().status === true)) {
            router.push("dashboard/products");
        } else {
            router.push("selfonboarding");
        }
   })
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried again as the user who has "status" == false. Then, I also went to the path /dashboard/products. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the code you have adapted? Please update your question with the new code, by clicking the edit link. Note that you need to really adapt the `if` clause. `if (doc.exists)` will not work whatever change you do in the `query` definition. A `QuerySnapshot` does not have an `exists` property.

Comment: I need to understand what you want to exactly do. It is not clear to me what is the business logic you want to implement in order to redirect the user to another page (`/dashboard/products`or `selfonboarding`). You query several documents: how do you decide the page to be redirect to depending on those **several** documents?

Comment: Sorry, the collection "proUser" has "status" field. And if it is true, the user will redirect to /dashboard/products. If it is false, the user will redirect to /selfonboarding. This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: The problem is that when you say "the collection "proUser" has "status" field" there may be **several** documents in this collection? How do you decide based on several documents? Or you know that there is only **one** document that has status = false in this collection.

Comment: All the documents in "proUser" collection have "status" field, so I need to check one by one, if  "status" is true or false.

Comment: Exactly. So for that you need to loop over the docs like you did with `userStatus.get().then((querySnapshot) => {querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {...})`. But what is the business logic there. **All** the documents needs to have status false? Or only one document needs to have status = false?

Comment: I edited my question to make all the thing clear, thank you very much for helping me a lot.

Comment: Is `pUiXp....` the id of the current user? I am not sure you need to look at ALL the documents in the collection `ProUser`, but just look at the value of status for the document corresponding to the user. Is that right? OR, you confirm that **ALL** the documents in the `ProUser` collection need to have status false?

Comment: Yes, I need the I’d of the current user. So I don’t think I need to look up all the user’s status too. So the issue is how I can retrieve current user id, and the use’s status valu to set the right path.

Comment: How do you select the user do in the collection, via the field `id` or via the `email`? Or the ID of the field corresponds to the user ID.

Comment: I want to select by the field id, not the email address.

Comment: Thank you so much! const userId = fireApp.auth().currentUser.uid; worked! I